# DopeSheet/GraphEditor : How to detect/change, with API, displayed frame range

Tags: python, graph-editor, dopesheet

Is there a way to detect (and change) displayed frame range in dopesheet and grapheditor using python API ?

I am not talking about frame start/ frame end or restricted frame range, but what is the lowest and highest frame visible on screen (that can be changed with scrolling for example)

I can't find data for now on API documentation.

Thanks !

Comment: Yes, I want to access this data by python API

Comment: You need to access the *View2D* of the region you want (so dope sheet for example). Then you need to change the context to this region and run these operators: https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.ops.view2d.html. You can also change the view2d direcly

Comment: Ok, I will check that. That answers "how to change" data, but it's only based on x/y delta, or zoom factor, but not on frame displayed

Comment: Yes, you cannot change that based on frames that fit into the window. You would have to calculate that from zoom factor, size of the region, and the xy delta.

Comment: Have a look at http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38939/focusing-the-graph-editor-area-to-a-custom-frame-keyframe-value-range  I found that having envelope modifiers on the fcurve didn't give me the focus I wanted on graph editor (using bpy.ops.graph.view*) to display soundbar BGL vis below and resorted to making a dummy 3 point action with the desired frame, value range and calling`bpy.ops.graph.view_all(c)` had the desired result.  You may find some of the other `bpy.ops.graph.view*` operators give you the focus you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frame, value from the region coords can be obtained from [view2d.region_to_view](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.types.View2D.html?highlight=view_to_region#bpy.types.View2D.region_to_view)

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
context = bpy.context
c = context.copy()
for i, area in enumerate(context.screen.areas):
    if area.type != 'GRAPH_EDITOR':
        continue
    region = area.regions[-1]
    print("SCREEN:", context.screen.name , "[", i, "]")
    c["space_data"] = area.spaces.active
    c["area"] = area
    c["region"] = region

    # region size
    h = region.height # screen
    w = region.width  # 
    bl = region.view2d.region_to_view(0, 0)
    tr = region.view2d.region_to_view(w, h)
    print("region bottom left (frame, value)", bl)
    print("region top right (frame, value)", tr)

    range = Vector(tr) - Vector(bl)
```

Note from [Getting area (region.view2d) pixel coordinates of 2D views (VSE, NLA)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38681/getting-area-region-view2d-pixel-coordinates-of-2d-views-vse-nla) how to get the scrollbar width.

As for setting the region to a desired frame value range, I have found using `bpy.ops.view2d.anything` an absolute nightmare, of finding rhyme or reason, and instead have used the methods outlined here [Focusing the graph editor area to a custom [frame, keyframe_value] range](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38939/focusing-the-graph-editor-area-to-a-custom-frame-keyframe-value-range) using `bpy.ops.graph.view*` operators in the graph editor, and I expect would work similarly in dope sheet for `bpy.ops.action.view*`.